# Discord.py bot tagging everyone

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a command that if used the bot tags everyone.

```
@client.command(aliases=['l'])
async def lol(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        message = await ctx.send("<@&EVERYONE_ROLE_ID>")
        await ctx.message.delete() # Delete user's message
```

The bot sends "@@everyone" instead of "@everyone".
No errors, how do I make it tag everyone?

Answer (score 1):

### Edited answer

So, to mention everyone you need to simply use the string `@everyone`

```
message = await ctx.send('@everyone')
```

If this doesn't work, in your client options try adding

```
client = commands.Bot(allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone = True))
```

Comment: The bot now sends:"<@693880813032570881>" instead of "@everyone".

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(aliases=['l'])
async def lol(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        message = await ctx.send(f'{ctx.guild.default_role}')
        await ctx.message.delete() # Delete user's message
```

Found the answer, `{ctx.guild.default_role}` instead of `ctx.guild.id`